# How to select elements via "select-by-selector" using part of the style attribute?

Tags: svg, syntax, css-selectors, command-line-interface, inkscape

This question relates to Inkscape version `1.1-dev (ede11a8, 2020-06-14)` running on Win10.

Consider the following SVG file, converted from PDF, which contains several `<path>` nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg2" xml:space="preserve" width="764.6533203125" height="476.9733276367188" viewBox="0 0 764.6533203125 476.9733276367188">
    <metadata id="metadata8">
        <rdf:RDF>
            <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                <dc:title/>
            </cc:Work>
        </rdf:RDF>
    </metadata>
    <defs id="defs6">
        <clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath824">
            <path d="M 82.31999999999999,240.36 H 598.44 V 543.48 H 82.31999999999999 Z" clip-rule="evenodd" id="path822" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g transform="matrix(1.333333333333333,0,0,-1.333333333333333,-55.83333350718022,736.0066664928191)" id="g714">
        <path id="path716" style="fill:none;stroke:#7f7f7f;stroke-width:0.24;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:0.72, 0.24;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" d="M 82.44000000000001,240.96 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,271.2 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,301.44 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,331.68 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,362.04 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,392.28 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,422.52 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,452.76 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,483 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,513.24 H 597.8399999999999 M 82.44000000000001,543.48 H 597.8399999999999" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(1.333333333333333,0,0,-1.333333333333333,-55.83333350718022,736.0066664928191)" id="g718">
        <path id="path720" style="fill:none;stroke:#7f7f7f;stroke-width:0.24;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:0.72, 0.24;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" d="M 82.44000000000001,543.48 V 240.96 M 143.04,543.48 V 240.96 M 203.64,543.48 V 240.96 M 264.36,543.48 V 240.96 M 324.96,543.48 V 240.96 M 385.56,543.48 V 240.96 M 446.28,543.48 V 240.96 M 506.88,543.48 V 240.96 M 567.48,543.48 V 240.96" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(1.333333333333333,0,0,-1.333333333333333,-55.83333350718022,736.0066664928191)" id="g722">
        <path id="path724" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.24;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:0.72, 0.24;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" d="M 82.44000000000001,240.96 H 597.84 V 543.48 H 82.44000000000001 Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(1.333333333333333,0,0,-1.333333333333333,-55.83333350718022,736.0066664928191)" id="g818">
        <g clip-path="url(#clipPath824)" id="g820">
            <path id="path826" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.92;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" d="M 384.24,247.4399999999999 384.6,247.0799999999999 384.84,246.7199999999999 385.2,246.4799999999999 385.4399999999999,246.24 385.8,246 386.04,245.7599999999999 386.3999999999999,245.5199999999999 386.6400000000001,245.3999999999999 387,245.2799999999999 387.24,245.0399999999999 387.6,244.9199999999999 387.84,244.7999999999999 388.2,244.68 388.4399999999999,244.4399999999999 388.8,244.1999999999999 389.04,244.0799999999999 389.3999999999999,243.8399999999999 389.6400000000001,243.7199999999999 390,243.5999999999999 390.24,243.4799999999999 H 390.6 L 390.84,243.36 H 391.2 L 391.4399999999999,243.24 391.8,243.1199999999999 H 392.04 L 392.3999999999999,243 392.6400000000001,242.8799999999999 393,242.7599999999999 393.36,242.6399999999999 393.6,242.5199999999999 393.9599999999999,242.3999999999999 H 394.2 394.56 394.8 395.16 L 395.3999999999999,242.2799999999999 H 395.7599999999999 L 396,242.1599999999999 396.36,242.0399999999999 H 396.72 396.9599999999999 397.3199999999999 397.56 397.92 L 398.16,241.9199999999999 H 398.52 L 398.7599999999999,241.7999999999999 H 399.12 399.48 399.72 L 400.0799999999999,241.68 H 400.3199999999999 400.68 400.92 401.2799999999999 401.6400000000001 401.88 402.24 L 402.48,241.56 H 402.84 403.0799999999999 L 403.4399999999999,241.4399999999999 H 403.8 404.04 404.3999999999999 404.6400000000001 405 L 405.36,241.56 H 405.6 405.9599999999999 406.2 406.56 406.92 407.16 407.52 407.7599999999999 408.12 408.48 L 408.72,241.4399999999999 H 409.0799999999999 409.4399999999999 L 409.68,241.3199999999999 H 410.04 410.2799999999999 L 410.6400000000001,241.4399999999999 H 411 411.24 L 411.6,241.3199999999999 H 411.9599999999999 412.2 412.56 412.8 413.16 413.52 413.7599999999999 414.12 L 414.48,241.1999999999999 H 414.72 415.0799999999999 415.4399999999999 415.68 416.04 416.3999999999999 416.6400000000001 417 417.24 417.6 417.9599999999999 418.2 418.56 L 418.92,241.3199999999999 419.16,241.1999999999999 H 419.52 419.88 420.12 420.48 420.84 421.2 421.4399999999999 421.8 422.16 422.3999999999999 422.7599999999999 423.12 423.36 423.72 424.0799999999999 424.3199999999999 424.68 425.04 425.3999999999999 425.6400000000001 426 L 426.36,241.0799999999999 H 426.6 426.96 L 427.32,241.1999999999999 H 427.56 427.92 428.28 428.6400000000001 428.88 429.24 429.6 429.96 430.2 430.56 430.92 L 431.16,241.0799999999999 H 431.52 431.88 432.24 432.48 432.84 433.2 433.56 433.8 434.16 434.52 434.88 435.12 435.48 L 435.84,241.1999999999999 H 436.2 436.4399999999999 436.8 L 437.16,241.0799999999999 H 437.52 437.88 L 438.12,240.9599999999999 H 438.48 438.84 439.2 439.4399999999999 L 439.8,241.0799999999999 H 440.16 440.52 440.88 441.12 L 441.48,240.9599999999999 H 441.84 442.2 M 328.0799999999999,424.7999999999999 328.3199999999999,429 328.56,434.2799999999999 328.8,438.72 329.04,442.56 329.3999999999999,447.36 329.6400000000001,451.68 329.88,454.68 330.12,458.3999999999999 330.36,462 330.72,464.7599999999999 330.9599999999999,467.7599999999999 331.2,470.64 331.44,472.9199999999999 331.8,475.4399999999999 332.04,477.9599999999999 332.2799999999999,479.5199999999999 332.52,481.1999999999999 332.76,483 333.12,484.3199999999999 333.36,485.3999999999999 333.6,486.4799999999999 333.84,487.4399999999999 334.2,488.64 334.44,489.72 334.68,490.3199999999999 334.92,491.1599999999999 335.2799999999999,491.64 335.52,492 335.76,492.72 336,492.8399999999999 336.36,492.9599999999999 336.6,493.68 336.84,493.9199999999999 H 337.08 L 337.44,494.1599999999999 337.68,494.2799999999999 337.92,494.3999999999999 338.16,494.8799999999999 338.52,495.2399999999999 H 338.76 L 339,495.1199999999999 339.24,495.36 H 339.6 L 339.84,495.1199999999999 340.08,495.36 340.3199999999999,495.5999999999999 H 340.68 L 340.92,495.8399999999999 H 341.16 L 341.52,496.0799999999999 341.76,496.3199999999999 342,495.9599999999999 342.24,495.5999999999999 342.6,495.8399999999999 H 342.84 L 343.08,496.1999999999999 343.3199999999999,496.5599999999999 343.68,496.4399999999999 H 343.92 L 344.16,496.7999999999999 344.52,496.9199999999999 344.76,497.04 H 345 L 345.24,496.7999999999999 345.6,496.4399999999999 345.84,496.5599999999999 346.08,496.68 346.44,496.5599999999999 346.68,496.4399999999999 346.92,496.3199999999999 347.2799999999999,496.0799999999999 347.52,495.9599999999999 347.76,495.8399999999999 348,495.5999999999999 H 348.36 348.6 L 348.84,495.1199999999999 349.2,494.64 349.44,494.1599999999999 349.68,494.04 350.04,494.2799999999999 350.2799999999999,494.1599999999999 350.52,493.3199999999999 350.88,492.8399999999999 351.12,492.5999999999999 351.36,491.8799999999999 351.72,491.3999999999999 351.9599999999999,491.5199999999999 352.1999999999999,491.2799999999999 H 352.56 L 352.8,491.04 353.04,490.0799999999999 353.4,489.36 H 353.6400000000001 L 353.8799999999999,488.7599999999999 354.24,488.1599999999999 354.48,488.04 354.72,487.1999999999999 355.08,486.4799999999999 H 355.3199999999999 L 355.56,486 355.92,485.1599999999999 356.16,484.9199999999999 356.4,484.68 356.76,483.9599999999999 357,483.72 357.24,483.5999999999999 357.6,482.64 357.8399999999999,482.04 358.08,481.7999999999999 358.44,480.72 358.68,479.8799999999999 H 358.92 L 359.2799999999999,479.04 359.5199999999999,477.8399999999999 H 359.8799999999999 L 360.12,477 360.36,475.3199999999999 360.72,474.72 360.9599999999999,473.8799999999999 361.1999999999999,471.4799999999999 361.56,470.1599999999999 361.8,469.0799999999999 362.04,466.7999999999999 362.4,464.7599999999999 362.6400000000001,463.3199999999999 363,460.1999999999999 363.24,457.3199999999999 363.48,455.64 363.8399999999999,452.1599999999999 364.08,447.9599999999999 364.44,445.4399999999999 364.68,441.8399999999999 364.92,436.3199999999999 365.2799999999999,432.6 365.5199999999999,428.64 365.76,422.64 366.12,417.9599999999999 366.36,413.3999999999999 366.72,406.68 366.9599999999999,401.04 367.1999999999999,396.8399999999999 367.56,389.8799999999999 367.8,383.2799999999999 368.16,378.9599999999999 368.4,372.9599999999999 368.6400000000001,366.3599999999999 369,361.68 369.24,355.68 369.6,348.7199999999999 369.8399999999999,344.3999999999999 370.1999999999999,339.7199999999999 370.44,333.4799999999999 370.68,329.3999999999999 371.04,325.4399999999999 371.2799999999999,319.56 371.6400000000001,314.8799999999999 371.8799999999999,311.5199999999999 372.12,306.9599999999999 372.48,302.8799999999999 372.72,300.1199999999999 373.08,296.64 373.3199999999999,293.0399999999999 373.68,290.3999999999999 373.92,287.2799999999999 374.16,283.92 374.5199999999999,282 374.76,279.9599999999999 375.12,276.9599999999999 375.36,274.92 375.72,273.24 375.9599999999999,270.8399999999999 376.3199999999999,269.04 376.56,267.8399999999999 376.8,266.04 377.16,264.48 377.4,263.5199999999999 377.76,262.3199999999999 378,260.8799999999999 378.36,259.92 378.6,258.9599999999999 378.9599999999999,258 379.1999999999999,257.1599999999999 379.56,256.1999999999999 379.8,255.4799999999999 380.16,254.6399999999999 380.4,253.9199999999999 380.6400000000001,253.0799999999999 381,252.36 381.24,251.7599999999999 381.6,251.1599999999999 381.8399999999999,250.56 382.1999999999999,250.0799999999999 382.44,249.7199999999999 382.8,249.24 383.04,248.8799999999999 383.4,248.5199999999999 383.6400000000001,248.1599999999999 384,247.7999999999999 384.24,247.4399999999999 M 277.92,241.1999999999999 H 278.16 278.4 278.6400000000001 278.88 279.12 279.36 L 279.6,241.0799999999999 H 279.84 L 280.08,241.1999999999999 H 280.32 L 280.56,241.0799999999999 H 280.8 281.04 281.28 281.52 281.76 282 L 282.24,240.9599999999999 H 282.48 L 282.72,240.8399999999999 H 282.96 283.2 L 283.44,240.9599999999999 283.68,241.0799999999999 283.92,241.1999999999999 H 284.16 L 284.4,241.3199999999999 H 284.6400000000001 L 284.88,241.1999999999999 285.12,241.0799999999999 H 285.36 L 285.6,240.9599999999999 H 285.84 L 286.08,241.0799999999999 H 286.32 286.56 L 286.8,241.1999999999999 H 287.04 287.28 L 287.52,241.3199999999999 H 287.76 L 288,241.1999999999999 H 288.24 288.48 288.72 288.9599999999999 289.2 289.44 289.68 289.92 290.16 L 290.4,241.3199999999999 H 290.6400000000001 290.88 L 291.12,241.1999999999999 H 291.36 291.6 L 291.84,241.3199999999999 H 292.2 292.44 292.68 292.92 293.16 293.4 293.6400000000001 293.88 294.12 L 294.36,241.4399999999999 H 294.6 L 294.84,241.56 H 295.08 L 295.3199999999999,241.68 H 295.56 295.8 L 296.04,241.56 H 296.2799999999999 296.52 296.76 L 297,241.68 H 297.36 297.6 297.84 298.0799999999999 298.3199999999999 298.56 298.8 L 299.04,241.7999999999999 299.2799999999999,241.9199999999999 H 299.52 299.7599999999999 300 L 300.24,242.0399999999999 H 300.48 300.84 L 301.0799999999999,242.1599999999999 H 301.3199999999999 301.56 301.8 302.04 302.2799999999999 L 302.52,242.2799999999999 H 302.7599999999999 L 303,242.3999999999999 303.24,242.5199999999999 303.48,242.6399999999999 303.84,242.7599999999999 304.0799999999999,242.8799999999999 304.3199999999999,243 304.56,243.1199999999999 H 304.8 L 305.04,243.36 305.2799999999999,243.4799999999999 H 305.52 305.7599999999999 L 306,243.5999999999999 H 306.36 L 306.6,243.7199999999999 306.84,243.8399999999999 307.0799999999999,243.9599999999999 307.3199999999999,244.0799999999999 307.56,244.3199999999999 307.8,244.4399999999999 308.04,244.68 308.2799999999999,244.9199999999999 308.6400000000001,245.1599999999999 308.88,245.2799999999999 309.12,245.5199999999999 309.36,245.7599999999999 309.6,245.8799999999999 309.84,246.1199999999999 310.0799999999999,246.4799999999999 310.3199999999999,246.7199999999999 310.56,247.0799999999999 310.92,247.3199999999999 311.16,247.56 311.3999999999999,247.9199999999999 311.6400000000001,248.2799999999999 311.88,248.7599999999999 312.12,249.1199999999999 312.36,249.5999999999999 312.6,250.0799999999999 312.9599999999999,250.4399999999999 313.2,250.9199999999999 313.4399999999999,251.5199999999999 313.68,252.1199999999999 313.92,252.8399999999999 314.16,253.56 314.3999999999999,254.1599999999999 314.7599999999999,254.8799999999999 315,255.5999999999999 315.24,256.56 315.48,257.3999999999999 315.72,258.4799999999999 315.9599999999999,259.3199999999999 316.2,260.7599999999999 316.56,261.6 316.8,262.4399999999999 317.04,263.5199999999999 317.2799999999999,265.0799999999999 317.52,266.7599999999999 317.7599999999999,268.3199999999999 318.12,269.5199999999999 318.36,271.0799999999999 318.6,273.24 318.84,275.16 319.0799999999999,277.0799999999999 319.3199999999999,279.6 319.68,281.8799999999999 319.92,283.92 320.16,286.68 320.3999999999999,289.56 320.6400000000001,291.9599999999999 320.88,295.3199999999999 321.24,298.92 321.48,301.56 321.72,304.68 321.9599999999999,308.8799999999999 322.2,312.7199999999999 322.4399999999999,316.4399999999999 322.8,320.9999999999999 323.04,324.9599999999999 323.2799999999999,329.04 323.52,334.1999999999999 323.7599999999999,338.8799999999999 324.12,343.4399999999999 324.36,349.1999999999999 324.6,354.2399999999999 324.84,358.68 325.0799999999999,364.68 325.4399999999999,370.8 325.68,375.48 325.92,381.12 326.16,387.4799999999999 326.3999999999999,392.3999999999999 326.7599999999999,397.7999999999999 327,404.1599999999999 327.24,409.0799999999999 327.48,414.1199999999999 327.72,420.24 328.0799999999999,424.7999999999999 M 244.08,241.1999999999999 H 244.32 L 244.56,241.0799999999999 H 244.68 244.92 245.16 245.4 245.64 245.88 246 246.24 246.48 246.72 246.96 247.2 L 247.32,240.9599999999999 H 247.56 L 247.8,241.0799999999999 H 248.04 248.28 248.52 248.64 248.88 249.12 249.36 L 249.6,240.9599999999999 H 249.84 250.08 250.2 250.44 250.68 250.92 L 251.16,241.0799999999999 251.4,240.9599999999999 H 251.52 251.76 L 252,240.8399999999999 252.24,240.7199999999999 H 252.48 252.72 252.96 L 253.08,240.8399999999999 253.32,240.9599999999999 H 253.56 253.8 L 254.04,240.8399999999999 H 254.28 L 254.52,240.9599999999999 H 254.64 254.88 255.12 L 255.36,240.8399999999999 H 255.6 255.84 L 256.08,240.9599999999999 256.32,241.0799999999999 256.44,241.1999999999999 H 256.68 L 256.92,241.3199999999999 257.16,241.1999999999999 257.4,241.0799999999999 H 257.6400000000001 L 257.88,240.9599999999999 H 258.12 258.24 258.48 L 258.72,240.8399999999999 H 258.96 259.2 259.44 L 259.68,240.9599999999999 259.92,241.0799999999999 H 260.16 L 260.28,241.1999999999999 H 260.52 260.76 261 261.24 261.48 L 261.72,241.0799999999999 H 261.96 262.2 262.44 L 262.56,241.1999999999999 H 262.8 263.04 263.28 263.52 L 263.76,241.0799999999999 H 264 264.24 264.48 264.72 264.96 L 265.08,241.1999999999999 H 265.32 265.56 L 265.8,241.0799999999999 266.04,240.8399999999999 H 266.28 266.52 266.76 L 267,240.9599999999999 H 267.24 L 267.48,241.0799999999999 H 267.72 L 267.84,241.1999999999999 H 268.08 L 268.32,241.3199999999999 H 268.56 L 268.8,241.1999999999999 H 269.04 L 269.28,241.0799999999999 269.52,240.9599999999999 H 269.76 270 270.24 L 270.48,241.0799999999999 H 270.72 L 270.96,241.1999999999999 H 271.2 L 271.32,241.0799999999999 H 271.56 L 271.8,240.9599999999999 H 272.04 L 272.28,240.8399999999999 H 272.52 272.76 273 L 273.24,240.9599999999999 273.48,241.0799999999999 H 273.72 273.96 274.2 274.44 274.68 274.92 275.16 275.4 275.6400000000001 275.88 L 276.12,240.9599999999999 H 276.24 276.48 276.72 L 276.96,241.0799999999999 H 277.2 277.44 L 277.68,241.1999999999999 H 277.92" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <path id="path1108" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.333333;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" d="M 0.1666664928197861,476.8066664928192 H 764.4866664928196 V 0.1666664928197861 H 0.1666664928197861 Z" />
</svg>
```

(The above is a simplified version of the file I intend to apply this procedure on – with the original file containing many more elements that need to be filtered out. Thus, "trivial" solutions like selecting by `id` (e.g. `path826`) or unique nesting (e.g. `g>g>g>path`) will not be possible in the real file.)

I would like to select `<path id="path826"...` via the CLI, by using some part of its `style` property, for example, `stroke-width:1.9`.

---

#### My Attempt

The [action](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/GtkAction_migration) list for this version gives among else:

```
...
quit-inkscape       :  Immediately quit Inkscape.
select              :  Select by ID (Deprecated)
select-all          :  Select all. Options: 'all' (every object including groups), 'layers', 'no-layers' (top level objects in layers), 'groups' (all groups including layers), 'no-groups' (all objects other than groups and layers, default).
select-by-class     :  Select by class
select-by-element   :  Select by SVG element (e.g. 'rect').
select-by-id        :  Select by ID
select-by-selector  :  Select by CSS selector
select-clear        :  Selection clear
select-invert       :  Invert selection. Options: 'all', 'layers', 'no-layers', 'groups', 'no-groups' (default).
select-list         :  Print a list of objects in current selection.
...
```

so I thought I could use the `select-by-selector` action to grab the node(s) I'm interested in. Next, I tried various selectors appearing on the [w3schools documentation page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), and while I got "simple" selectors like `g>path` to work, the more relevant selectors (containing `[]`, `:`, `~=`, etc.) eluded me. Inkscape's warning hinted that part of the problem is that character like `;` and `:` (which often appear in `style` strings) are interpreted as new commands/arguments by the Inkscape CLI. I assume these characters need to be escaped somehow or surrounded by some special quotes to be recognized correctly, so I tried the following (didn't work):

```
select-by-selector:path[style*="stroke-width:1.9"]        // selects nothing
select-by-selector:path[style~="stroke-width:1.9"]        // selects nothing
select-by-selector:path[style\*="stroke-width\:1.9"]      // selects nothing
select-by-selector:path\[style\*\="stroke-width\:1.9\"\]  // selects almost everything
etc.
```

I could not find official documentation on the selectors supported by this Inkscape action <sup>[[1](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html),[2](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/master/src/actions/actions-selection.cpp)]</sup> and how they should be specified (escaped characters?).

So **the question is**: how to use the `select-by-selector` action to match a substring of the `style` attribute?

---

**Additional information**
I later tried adding the desired type of selector using the GUI (Selectors and CSS panel, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>), but the dialog refused since it's supposedly "invalid" (although the example is a verbatim copy from w3schools):

[image]

Comment: Please report bugs and feature requests to the project directly at https://inkscape.org/report . Also, please update to 1.0, to verify that the problem still exists in the released version, or try a development version, to see if it has been solved already.

Comment: @Moini I was under the impression that I had a pretty current version. I had no reason to suspect it was a bug when working with the CLI (the original version of the question), only after stumbling upon the same feature in the GUI did this possibility arise. I'll definitely try the latest [development version](https://inkscape.org/release/master/) and update this post accordingly and/or submit a bug report.

Comment: Posted a bug report here: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/3070

Comment: Thank you, @Dev-iL!